# How to redirect when receive Onesignal push notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, onesignal

I need to redirect to some specific Widget/Page of my app when the user clic on the push notification. I tried something like this but not working:

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
  Navigator.of(context)
          .push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new Detail('Title', 'Description', 'Hour', 'User', 'Image');
      }));
});
```